# Bash or PHP script on php session timeout

Tags: php, apache, cron

I'm currently building a web application for the management of an association. In that app, the users are able to build eMails, and send them to different members of the association.

The user can also, while writing the eMail, provide some attachement files, uploaded by Ajax for a more user-friendly experience. Every time a user wants to upload an image for instance, he will trigger an Ajax request, downloading the file into the server "temp" folder through a classic file upload form. I then extract the file from this temp folder using `$_FILES` to save it in a custom "temp" folder, with a token named folder, so that I can gather all the attachements there and re-use them when the user wants to actually send the eMail. When the eMail is sent, the files are moved from the custom "temp" folder to another, immuable location for archiving. Only if he sends the mail. If he quits the page or log off, the folder and files are deleted by php.

But sometimes, after creating a new eMail and uploading some documents, the user will simply skip to another website, and never log off or quit the page properly. So, to prevent my server to be crowded with ghost temp files, I need a system to delete the remaining files.

I've already thought of a Cron task that would run for instance every 24h, and deleting every files older than that. But I'd like my solution to be portative and easy to install (--> Php only, no particular server setup), so **I'd like to know if I can make PHP automatically run a macro that would delete the files on the session timeout or log off.**

I haven't managed to find anything yet, and some help would be appreciated. Is my intended solution only actually possible?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php  PHP's standard sessions handler has no "user notifier" capacity. There is no way for it to run some of your code (e.g. the file cleanup stuff) when it runs. You'll have to roll your own. As for the logoff stuff, that's trivial and utterly under your control already anyways.

Comment: On (most?) linux systems, PHP garbage collection (= session files deletion) is already done by a cronjob. See `/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime`. It's running the command `[ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean /var/lib/php5 $(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime)`

Comment: Still i think simple cron will suffice (with check that file has been in this folder at least for some amount of time reasonable, a day maybe).

Comment: @Cthulhu You're probably right, furthermore this page will only be use a moderatly amount of times a day so I don't need a huge reactivity or optimization. I just wanted to do something maybe more "classy", just to know how to do it.

Comment: @MarcB So you mean I need to create an object implementing `SessionHandlerInterface`, and overriding the `gc()` method for instance? Would that work?

Comment: @MarcB Oh... I would need to override every other methods as well, right?

Comment: php's own cleanup routines runs indepedently of the custom handlers. it just scans the session files for any expired ones and nukes them. it does NOT have a call back to let you intercept that cleanup. So you have to implement the entire session system yourself, and provide your own cleanup function.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Interesting... So you're implying that I can somehow introduce my cleaning routine in the preconfigured php sessionCleaning one?

Comment: @MarcB Ok, so, that seems WAY to much painful and insecured to be done! But what's the point of `SessionHandlerInterface` then? Anyway, I'll go for the CRON task then. If you might explain and sum all of this in an answer, I would gladly accept it!

Comment: because it lets you re-implement the session system yourself, using whatever back-end storage you want (database, memcache, etc...). but that stuff exists only at the per-user level. PHP's own session cleanup handler exists above all that.